# NginX redirect on index.html if visitor's Address is a certain IP

Tags: nginx

My problem is that I'm doing some side work besides regular job.

I would like to avoid someone to visit my page from work. The site loads index.html as default, but I have an index.php on the site what I would like see, so can't just redirect everyone from "**workip**" to some othe site...

So what I would like is:
If source is "**work IP**" and goes to "**http://www.mydomain.com/index.html**" be redirected to www.google.com but not on other pages.

Any idea how to get this done in NginX?

I've just got it figured out...

```
location /index.html {
 if ($remote_addr = 1.2.3.4 ) {
  rewrite ^ http://www.google.com/;
 }
}
```

Comment: Maybe this question is more appropriate for http://serverfault.com/ StackOverflow is focused mainly in development stuff

Comment: if you can't find solution to this and need a quick dirty fix try this: download a plugin for your browser (like this one [link](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/)) to change your browsers default user agent, give a name like "dont worry its me" and check in your php script if not `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']=="dont worry its me"` do a redirect `header("Location: http://www.google.com/");
die();` not posting this as an answer, i know its dirty.

Comment: @TiborPeterToth post it as an answer, you can do it even if its your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an NGINX location block:

```
location /index.html {
   if ($remote_addr = 1.2.3.4 ) {
      rewrite ^ http://www.google.com/;
   }
}
```